# How to position two blocks of text where one block is composed of two blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: Something like this]

Here, the red and black are two blocks of text with the same width as the blue, but together, both blocks have the same height as the blue.
Currently, I have [image: this].

Comment: What's your CSS look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modern approach using a nested [flexbox layout](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). It unfortunately needs some extra markup (container divs), but is very flexible in terms of width and height, which is extremely hard to achieve with other methods. You need to play with the flex values (flex-grow, flex-shrink,flex-base) to achieve the results you want. It behaves pretty much like table cells though.

A good starting point to wrap your head around flexbox is [this nice overview](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). The height on the black container is just to demonstrate, that the elements scale nicely to every dimensions you want. Notice, that the right side expands to the same size despite no height being declared.

```css
div{padding:5px;}

#container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;
}
#container > div{
   flex:1 1 auto;  
}
#left{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
#left > div{
   flex:1 1 auto;   
}
#red{background-color:red;}
#black{background-color:black;color:white;height:100px;}
#right{
   background:#aaf;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="red">
    red container
    </div>
    <div id="black">
      black container
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="right">
    right
    <br>
    side
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have fixed height for red and black boxes as well. What is so different in your code except that your right box does not have fixed height?

Comment: It's just to demonstrate that the boxes adapt to every height and width you want. As you can see, I have no height declared on the right container, but still it has the exact height like the left side because it scales accordingly. If the right box was taller than the left side, the black and red box would scale accordingly. You might want to plat with the code a bit. A nice overview is https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and the link.

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to upvote if you think this is a good answer;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this example that I created [HERE](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/MaRgxV?editors=110).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="two">
   <div id="red">red div</div>
   <div id="black">black div</div>
</div>
<div class="one">
   <div id="blue">blue div</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.two {
   width: 48%;
   margin: 0 1%;
   float: left;
}
.one {
   width: 48%;
   float: left;
}
#red {
   background: red;
   height: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   color: white;
   overflow: auto;
}
#black {
   background: black;
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   color: white;
   overflow: auto;
}
#blue {
  background: #CFE2F3;
  height: 62px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

In this example, the red and black textboxes have the same height and width but they sit on top of each other. The blue box has the same width as the first two blocks but its height is twice the height of red block.

Comment: i see one flaw with this - you use fixed heights to achieve it. This probably is not feasible in most cases.

Comment: @Christoph: If the content is fixed, then I think you agree with me that it is feasible. But if the content is dynamic, you never can guarantee that the content of the red and black boxes have similar length. So you still can use fixed height with `overflow: auto`. I have updated the example to show that.

Comment: Actually you can - with a simple flexbox layout. I'll post an answer for that.